# Php SOAP: как установить параметры в xml ?

Tags: xml, php, request, soap

Нужно отправить вот такой xml:

```
<soapenv:Body>
<var:BookLabelRequest senderCity="Ort - City" senderPostalCode="12345" senderBoxNumber="" senderStreetNumber="Nr" senderStreet="Strasse - Street" senderContactPhone="" senderCareOfName="CareofName" senderName2="Nachname - Name" senderName1="Vorname - Firstname" labelFormat="PDF" customerReference="Customer Reference" shipmentReference="Shipment Reference" deliveryName="Deutschland_Var3" portalId="OnlineRetoure"/>
```

</soapenv:Body>

А именно:

```
BookLabelRequest senderCity="Ort - City" senderPostalCode="12345" senderBoxNumber=""
```

Вот полный xml, который я должен отправить:`<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:var="https://amsel.dpwn.net/abholportal/gw/lp/schema/1.0/var3bl" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">
            <wsse:UsernameToken>
                <wsse:Username>ws_online_retoure</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">Anfang1!</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <var:BookLabelRequest senderCity="Ort - City" senderPostalCode="12345" senderBoxNumber="" senderStreetNumber="Nr" senderStreet="Strasse - Street" senderContactPhone="" senderCareOfName="CareofName" senderName2="Nachname - Name" senderName1="Vorname - Firstname" labelFormat="PDF" customerReference="Customer Reference" shipmentReference="Shipment Reference" deliveryName="Deutschland_Var3" portalId="OnlineRetoure"/>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>`

Comment: И Еще:
Как дебажить soapclent???
Как посмотреть какой xml получается? А то критическая ошибка "Uncaught SoapFault exception: [var3bl:InvalidXml] Invalid XML"
А я не знаю как посмотреть этот xml...

Comment: может быть [это][1] поможет
[1]: http://habrahabr.ru/post/187390/

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте почитать [Работа с веб-серверами на php посредством SOAP](http://habrahabr.ru/post/38370/), ну или на крайний случай [здесь](http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?lr=213&text=php+soap), а вот [здесь](http://oooportal.ru/?cat=article&id=798) конкретно про посылку SOAP-запросов, и вопрос сразу: Пробовали сразу в адресную строку зафуячить сам запрос?

Comment: К сожалению это не то. Я понимаю как это делать, как в том примере. В мануале намного больше написано чем там )). Меня больше даже интересует как посмотреть сформированный XML???
Даже если он с ошибкой...

Comment: от кого - кому? то, что в ответ приходит? так вам в ответ ничего и не приходит...

Comment: Я обновил шапку. Предоставил полный xml который я должен отправлять.
Сервер предоставляет wsdl файл со схемой.
Я решил использовать SoapClient для этих целей.
С авторизацией мне кажется вопрос решен. Но теперь меня интересует как сформировать такую строку
<var:BookLabelRequest senderCity="Ort - City" senderPostalCode="12345" senderBoxNumber="" />

Comment: Меня больше даже интересует как посмотреть сформированный XML перед отправкой???
А так вызывает ошибку, что невалидный xml

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php#97273 Вот тут есть решение проблемы. Но вопрос по дебагу остался открытым